# Price schedule for freemium app?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

While trying to submit an app for review, there is a section called "Price Schedule". I am not sure what to place for my app, it is technically free to download, use, and create an account on, but more features can be unlocked using a subscription.

Given this, what kind of "Price Schedule" should I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is free to download, choose the Free option. You don’t need to schedule a change in the price.